# use static button to check the values and display on screen

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uibutton

From server i use to get 1 or 2 or 3 values. And i designed one screen with 3 static buttons. Because the values will not exceed more than 3.Now from server i am getting the vlaue from one variable.

Now if 3 values comes measn it working.if only 2 or 1 value is coming measn its crashing .Here my code:

```
if (er.code == 102){



                   let Data  = data as! String

                    let dataString = String(describing: data!)

                    if let stringToData = dataString.data(using: .utf8) {
                        do {

                            self.arrayOfData =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: stringToData, options: []) as! [String]



                            if self.arrayOfData == [self.arrayOfData[0]] {

                                 self.sugOptionOne?.setTitle(self.arrayOfData[0], for: .normal)


                            }
                            else  if self.arrayOfData == [self.arrayOfData[1]] {

                             self.sugOptionTwo?.setTitle(self.arrayOfData[1], for: .normal)


                            }
                            else  if self.arrayOfData == [self.arrayOfData[2]] {

                                self.sugOptionThree?.setTitle(self.arrayOfData[2], for: .normal)

                            }


        } catch {
                            print(error.localizedDescription)
                        }
                    }



                }
```

Is there any other way to handle this.please help me out.Thanks

Comment: What does this even mean? `self.arrayOfData == [self.arrayOfData[0]]`? Use `self.arrayOfData.count == 1` to check the counting, not whatever you are doing, you are subscript the array while there's no value available, it cause crash

Comment: use if let or guard to check if the value is present or get the array count first and then try to set the button title according to array count

Comment: @Tj3n   from my arrayOfData i will get data like ["1","2"]. Some times 1 value or 3 value...Sow what i did...if self.arrayOfData == [self.arrayOfData[0]] measn ..if that arrayOfData is == to first value just print / set the first button tiltle.....now its only crashing

Comment: @hybridDev you are comparing `array ["1","2"]` with data `@"1"` ...which is confusing. even if array will contain single value ,its an array only. for eg :`array ["1"]` with data `@"1"`...its still wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this with using two different method

1 Method : Using UICollectionView to handle dynamic numbers (Preferred)

2 Method : For Lopp

This code based on your question that you will have maximum 3 values in array and object type would be String (from your code above)

```
for (index, value) in self.arrayOfData.enumerated() {

    let titleString : String = value as! string

    switch index {
        case 0:
            self.OptionOne?.setTitle(titleString, for: .normal)
        break
        case 1:
            self.OptionTwo?.setTitle(titleString, for: .normal)
        break
        case 2:
            self.OptionThree?.setTitle(titleString, for: .normal)
            break
        default:
            break

    }
}
```

Comment: i am not sure what are you trying  to achieve

Comment: @NazmulHasan go through you will know

Comment: self.arryOfData is array, with for it will loop through it, as in question mentioned that it will have max 3 items with switch case you will have appropriate value.

Comment: before downvoting just strech your brain and see output

Comment: @Dev_Tandel    i have one doubt...should i need to chnage to collection view for this..or by using the same 3 uibutton can i handle this ?

Comment: for the for loop you don't need to use collection view

Comment: if you want to use collectionview you dont need your 3 buttons.

Comment: @Dev_Tandel op question has this line `self.arrayOfData == [self.arrayOfData[0]]` What does this even mean? i am not sure .. what do you think ?

Comment: yes it make no sense , so i gave new approach to achieve what he is been trying to do.

Comment: @Dev_Tandel yea approach is  correct ! but avoid download .. before write answer try to understand OP view . however i remove downvote

Comment: @Dev_Tandel someting like this answer i was make sure from OP to provide alternative option avoid down voted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43698805/how-to-use-a-detail-disclosure-button-in-uicollectionviewcell

Comment: @Dev_Tandel   i ahve updated my full method but i dont know hoe to handle ur solution with that my method ....

Comment: @hybridDev we are not sure where  are stuck could you clear .. what you try to achieve and give json response

Comment: @NazmulHasan   from my `arrayOfData` i will get data like ["1","2"]. Some times 1 value or 3 value...Sow what i did...if `self.arrayOfData == [self.arrayOfData[0]]` measn ..if that `arrayOfData` is ==  to first value just print / set the first button tiltle.....now its only crashing

Comment: @hybridDev share code declaration `arrayOfData`  and api response

Comment: ` var arrayOfData: [String] = []  ` declared globally  , the my op code follos

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148961/discussion-between-nazmul-hasan-and-hybrid-dev).

Comment: @Nazmul Hasan   you there  ??

Answer (score 0):

I think @Dev_Tandel is almost correct. Just try this

```
for (index, value) in self.arrayOfData.enumerated() {

let titleString : String = value 

switch index {
    case 0:
        self.OptionOne?.setTitle(titleString, for: .normal)
    break
    case 1:
        self.OptionTwo?.setTitle(titleString, for: .normal)
    break
    case 2:
        self.OptionThree?.setTitle(titleString, for: .normal)
        break
    default:
        break
}}
```